# Restarting a website from its own webpage

Tags: asp.net, iis

Well, just to keep it simple: I have a webform. On it a button called "Restart". I click on this button and IIS will restart itself.

Now, what would be the C# code that I would need to write behind the OnClick event of this web button? (If it's even possible?)

---

Then a second button is added. It's called "Reset" and should just reset the AppDomain for the current web application. What would be the code for this?

Comment: What do you want to Restart... the whole IIS instance or just this particular app?

Comment: Actually, both. There's another application on the same IIS server that tends to eat up resources without releasing them. Thus a restart just fixes this in an easy way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
protected void Reload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
}

protected void Restart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var sc = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController("IISAdmin"))
    {
        sc.Stop();
        sc.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be a good option as it will only restart your application and not the other applications hosted on that server.

Answer (score 3):

```
Process iisreset = new Process();
iisreset.StartInfo.FileName   = "iisreset.exe";
iisreset.StartInfo.Arguments = "computer name";
iisreset.Start();

//iisreset.exe is located in the windows\system32 folder.
```

Answer (score 1):

(http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t300488-how-can-i-restart-iis-or-server-from-aspx-page-or-web-service.html)

```
string processName = "aspnet_wp";

System.OperatingSystem os = System.Environment.OSVersion;

//Longhorn and Windows Server 2003 use w3wp.exe
if((os.Version.Major == 5 && os.Version.Minor > 1) || os.Version.Major ==6)
   processName = "w3wp";

foreach(Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName(processName))
   {
      Response.Write("Killing ASP.NET worker process (Process ID:" +
      process.Id + ")");
      process.Kill();
   }
```

Comment: Be careful killing processes like this. It could have unexpected behaivours. Iisreset.exe will do all the taks needed to restart the iss, and it doesn't make a hard kill to the aspnet_wp for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Is there more than one web site hosted on the server where this code will run?  If so, you may want to look at the System.DirectoryServices namespace, and restart the individual web site

Comment: There are several web sites hosted on this server, but the application that can do the reset is meant to reset them all. It's supposed to maintain those other sites.